# Python Type Error: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, function, error-handling

So forgive me a little here as im new to python just coming over from JS im having an issue running a string through a function which is meant to return a coloured text for console

```py
File "d:\Dev\DiscordIdleBotPython\venv\ccolours.py", line 16, in colourDyn
    return(f'{colours[colour]}{text}{colours["CCLEAR"]}')
              ~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not 'str'

coloursAvailable={
  "CCLEAR": '\033[0m',
  "COGREEN": '\33[42m'
  }
def colourDyn(text, colour):
  colours=coloursAvailable[colour]

  if colour not in colours: print('colour undefined or not available')
  
  print("function passed colour check")
  return(f'{colours[colour]}{text}{colours["CCLEAR"]}')
```

Im clearly formatting something wrong but i don't know where perhaps im not even searching the array correctly?

any help appreciated

Comment: The error message is telling you everything you need to know. `colours` is a string, you're indexing into `colours` with another variable `colour` that is also a `str`, and `colour` is not allowed to be. `colour` must be an `int` to be used as written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try colours=coloursAvailable in the first line of colourDyn.

Currently, you are already getting the colour from coloursAvailable, thus the error.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like reassigned the value of colour to be a particular colour here:
`colours=coloursAvailable[colour]` so when you later try to index colours, it's already been reassigned to whatever `coloursAvailable[colour]` is.

As suggested in the other answer, you can fix by instead doing `colours=coloursAvailable` or just delete that line and use `coloursAvailable` directly.